# Excel 2007 VBA to select range of cells

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am attempting to select a range of cells.  I have done this before but am having trouble with the syntax.

```
Sub ChgDateX()

Range("A41").Select

Do
    If ActiveCell.Value = "Last Updated" Then
    mydate = ActiveCell.Offset(-40, 0).Value

    'Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9)).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = mydate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = mydate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = mydate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = mydate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = mydate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = mydate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value = mydate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value = mydate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value = mydate

    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Else: ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = "" & ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 0).Value = ""

End Sub
```

I am trying to get away from the individual offset = mydate type coding.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Tim I have a date housed from the active cell, .Offset(-1,-39) That I want to overwrite the existing values in the range group I am having trouble referencing.

Comment: I have not placed the additional code for the passing of the If statment.

Comment: Original Post edited for clarity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things:

This code:

```
Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = "" & ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 0).Value = ""
```

Doesn't work as expected because the correct operator you're looking for is `And` and not `&`

You don't have to "Select" anything. You can just put a reference to a cell in a variable (see my code).

Also, since you are always moving down to the next cell in the loop, you can put that outside of the `IF` statement.

Based on your code I think you're looking for something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim myDate As Date

    Set r = Range("A41")

    Do
        If (r.Value = "Last Updated") Then
            myDate = r.Offset(-40, 0).Value

            With Range(r.Offset(0, 1), r.Offset(0, 9))
                .Value = myDate
                .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
            End With
        End If

        Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop Until r.Value = vbNullString And r.Offset(-3, 0).Value = ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ActiveCell.Range("B1:J1").Value = MyDate
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this ... with 1 note. I wouldn't advise the looping like this. Perhaps you can filter on `Column A <> ""` or something, then just loop through the visible cells? Hard to say without knowing what you are doing.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChgDateX()

Range("A41").Select

Do
    If ActiveCell.Value = "Last Updated" Then

        Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9)).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-40, 0).Value

        ActiveCell.EntireRow.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

    End If

    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select

Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = "" & ActiveCell.Offset(-3, 0).Value = ""

End Sub
```